# onClick for dynamically generated LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, event-handling, linkbutton

In my sharepoint web-part application. I am dynamically generating LinkButtons as below. and this works fine

```
foreach (var pName in productTypesNames[productType] )
{
   var subLi = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
   var linkButton = new LinkButton{ Text = pName };
   linkButton.Click += new EventHandler(linkButton_Click);
   subLi.Controls.Add(linkButton);
   ul.Controls.Add(subLi);
}
```

However, when I click on one of the links in UI, my debugger never hits the breakpoint that is set at very first line of

```
void linkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

---

More Code

```
protected void StateClicked(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
  //Generate a dictionary of type Dictionary<string, List<string>>
  //Display the dictionary
  foreach (var productType in productTypesNames.Keys)
        {
            var li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            nav.Controls.Add(li);
            var ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");

            var anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
            anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "#");

            foreach (var pName in productTypesNames[productType] )
            {
                var subLi = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                var linkButton = new LinkButton{ Text = pName };
                linkButton.Click += new EventHandler(linkButton_Click);
                subLi.Controls.Add(linkButton);
                ul.Controls.Add(subLi);
            }
            anchor.InnerHtml = productType;
            li.Controls.Add(anchor);
            li.Controls.Add(ul);
        }
 }
```

Where stateClicked is called by a click on the image map of USA.

Comment: There could be a number of reasons for this, more code is needed, the most likely reasons could be AutoEventWireup="false", or missing runat="Server" on the linkButtons.

Comment: I added following code and still doesn't like it :-(

Comment: linkButton.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                    linkButton.Attributes.Add("AutoEventWireup", "true");
                    linkButton.Attributes.Add("AutoPostBack", "true");
                    linkButton.Click += new EventHandler(linkButton_Click);

Comment: Also this is a Sharepoint web-part application

Comment: Make sure your controls are recreated at each postback or the event wont get wired properly. If you only create those control on the onclick, make sure you recreate them somewhere else, like page_init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably aren't recreating the dynamically generated links on every postback.

If you have a `if (!IsPostback)` wrapped around your foreach, try removing it.

Comment: I don't have     if (!IsPostback) wrapped around my     foreach :-(

Comment: Can you post more code?  It works fine if I copy your code directly into my project.  The only way I reproduce it is if I don't re-create the links on postback

Comment: Ok, so is StateClicked called sometime during postback?  Probably still going to need more code to solve this completely.  Also see @CjCoax's comment regarding AutoEventWireup

Comment: Yes, and there is no check for (!IsPostback) anywhere. I added following attributes to linkButton. linkButton.Attributes.Add("runat", "server"); linkButton.Attributes.Add("AutoEventWireup", "true"); linkButton.Attributes.Add("AutoPostBack", "true"); linkButton.Click += new EventHandler(linkButton_Click);

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem here ....

i was creating an `HtmlTable` after firing an event...
this table has (n) `HtmlTableRow`s (calculated in the event handler)
now each row contains 2 `LinkButton`s that are generated from the code behind .. after an event is handled...
and each `LinkButton` is assigned a new event handler:

`lnkbtnEdit.CommandArgument = b.BookID.ToString();

lnkbtnEdit.Click += new EventHandler(lnkbtnEdit_Click);`
where `lnkbtnEdit_Click` signature is as follows:
`protected void lnkbtnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

the weird thing is that .. there is a postback when i click the generated `LinkButton`... but the event was not firing...

i don't know exactly what the problem was ... but i found the solution: ..
it appears as if these generated controls disappear on the postback (tried to assign an id and used `Page.FindControl()` witch returned with null !!)

so i had to re-link the buttons.... on the Page_Load i re-generated the LinkButtons, with same ID... and linked them to their respective `EventHandler`s